# Powershell return matching row from SQL query results from AD Computer list

Tags: powershell, filtering

I'm lost, apologies if similar questions to this have been asked before. All my searching has come up empty.

How can I iterate through SQL query results in `$Results` matching server names in `$servers` if it helps, is created using

```
#Change OS to OperatingSystem, shortened for screen readability.
$servers = Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(|(OS=*2003*)(OS=*2000*))" | Select -expand Name
```

I got as far as trying this:

```
$servers | ForEach-Object { $Results.Server -match $_}
```

But the output contains multiple duplicate items at the end.

I also had thought of producing a huge SQL query, so only one query needs to be run, as an example:

```
$SqlQuery = @'
SELECT swName AS [Server], swSchedule as [Schedule]
 FROM SW_TABLE
WHERE (swSchedule = 'Weekly' OR swSchedule = 'SCCM - Weekly' OR swSchedule = 'Monthly')
AND swRootObjectType = 'Server'
AND swName = 'Server'
AND swName = 'Server'
AND swName = 'Server'
AND swName = 'Server'
'@
```

Comment: `$servers |Where-Object {$Results.Server -contains $_.Name}`

Comment: I can feel my sanity returning! Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen, how would I get the Server,Schedule as output.

Comment: In that case you would want to do it the other way around (filter `$Results.Server` based on `$servers`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the `$Results` array based on whether `$servers` contain the `Server` name property:

```
$Results |Where-Object { $servers -contains $_.Server }
```

Comment: This is where I lose my sanity, `$servers` contains 75 items, `$Results` contains 996 but when I run this filter, I end up with 88 items. Which is a error introduced when `$servers` is UNSORTED.

Comment: @user4317867 could you update your question with how you obtain `$servers` (full command)?

Comment: It's nothing fancy, just Get-ADComputer with an LDAPFilter piped to Select -Expand Name

Comment: There's nothing insane in getting more than 75 items, assuming that `$Results` have multiple rows with the same `Server` name. But you're getting a different result if you do `$servers = $servers |Sort-Object` prior to filtering?

Comment: If I check, I see no duplicates and I forgot to include the SELECT DISTINCT in the query above. For sanity, I put the data into Excel and ran a vlookup, only one row wasn't found.

Comment: Going to mark this as correct, I've moved into a more manual procedure and will need to re-visit this at some point.